# Stop Gmail notifications for specific senders

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

I'm using Gmail in a Chrome tab on Windows 10, and it's set up to produce notifications for new emails. There are some senders for which I'd like to not get notifications for.

There is a trick based on archiving the email, but I'd prefer a solution where the email is still in the usual inbox.

Comment: Are you talking about the Gmail notifications on the Windows notification panel?

Comment: @Rubén it's pop-up notifications. I think generated by Chrome, presented by Windows